# Why was File.Delete designed not to throw when the file does not exist?

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

From [MSDN File.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

It seems like a bad practice to have low level api's hiding exceptional conditions and indeed this seems like a rare case.  What was the motivation on this one?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, it's like it was already deleted it.

Comment: But what if there is a bug in your program and you passed the wrong name in.  Extra slash, etc.

Comment: If you want to check the existence of a file then use `File.Exists`. `File.Delete` responsibility is to delete a file.

Comment: I would not consider File.Delete to be a "low level API"

Comment: If you pass the wrong name it could end up deleting the wrong file.  It will throw if you pass it an invalid path though.

Comment: If it exists it does not say, too.

Comment: @dotctor And you should rarely ever use File.Exists since that information might not be relevant in the next line of code.

Comment: Analogy--sign at the airport "Remove all articles of Netal before entering the terminal."  Someone should throw an exception.

Comment: The intention is to delete the file so it no longer exists. If it _already_ doesn't exist, then there is nothing more to do.

Comment: I don't understand your analogy. Netal Is Metal? In that case if you don't have any items of metal your job is done. No need to throw an exception.

Comment: @MartinSmith The point of throwing the exception is that the sign needs to be fixed.

Comment: @crokusek Your analogy is this: Airport personnel perform a `Person.Delete(metal)`, but `Person` has no metal on them. You want the employee to "throw an exception", but Microsoft thinks they should just silently continue; in terms of your analogy and in terms of programming, doing nothing makes more sense.

Comment: @Quantic so your fine with leaving that sign broken with the mispelling?  Only an exception (talking to terminal manager, etc, will fix the sign).

Comment: @crokusek Yes. I want the `CheckSpelling(sign)` to throw an exception. The method that checks for metal should do nothing if there's no metal. In this case you are thinking of, `CheckSpelling(null)`, do you want `CheckSpelling` to throw an exception when there's no sign? That's the analogy, "Delete a file. File not found: throw or not throw? -> don't throw"; "Remove metal. Metal not found: throw or not throw? -> don't throw"; "Read sign. Sign not found: throw or not throw? -> throw"; "Check spelling on sign; sign found, sign has incorrect spelling -> throw."

Comment: Keep in mind that if it fails to delete a file that *does* exist, it **will** throw an exception.

Comment: With file system access it is always difficult to choose the right approach and they do it in this way because it is probably the lesser evil. Suppose that File.Delete throws on inexistant files. Now every File.Delete should be preceeded by a File.Exists to avoid the exception (And you don't want to drive your code by catching exceptions right?) But File.Exists cannot guarantee the existance of the file **at the time** when File.Delete runs (perhaps another thread or process deletes it?) So the framework will be the cause of you writing incorrect code

Comment: If the method name is "File.Delete" then the literal responsibility is to **perform the action** of  "deleting a file".  If that action does not occur then something went wrong.  That would be kiss.  A new method name called "File.DeleteIfExists" or "File.EnsureDeleted" would advertise the issue and not hide this detail in the docs.  Looks like question will be closed anyway.  Thanks for the debate.  I'm very surprised that nearly all comments were against my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to delete a non-existent file, it is already deleted, so that is not exceptional. Another reason is that a race condition could be created if you tried to confirm the file's existence before deleting:

[Should I call File.Exists before calling File.Delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410056/should-i-call-file-exists-before-calling-file-delete)

> This removes an extra operation and avoids any kind of race window.

Comment: Why is there some competition going on for deleting files?  That seems like a rare case and not what the basic call should be expected to handle.  The competition cases could be handled as separate code.

Comment: They aren't competition cases, they are two things trying to do the same task. If they are both trying to delete a file and one of them deletes it first, the second one shouldn't care. It was trying to delete the file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a restaurant that has a "*No Pets Allowed*" or "*No Guns Allowed*" sign at the door, and there is a scanner to check for that.

Now let's say you do not have a pet nor a gun, would you raise your hand to say that you do not have one? Would any entrance security raise a hand to say that you do not have one? or you just move on to the scanner and continue?

So no, Delete will just remove either it exists or not, without throwing any exception, give a flag or a status. To Check before removing you could use `File.Exists()`. And it is good practice to do that before creating or deleting a file.